# Odd Problem with luabind::object

Tags: lua, luabind

I'm currently using luabind, specifically https://github.com/rpavlik/luabind since the official release is outdated and doesn't compile with the latest version of boost anymore.

I'm getting a very odd problem that I can't find anywhere on the net. I managed to reduce the case to a very simple scenario.

In one module I will have:

```
luabind::object value;

void functionA() {
    lua_pushstring(L,"yo");
    luabind::object temp(luabind::from_stack(L,-1));
    value = temp;
}
```

In another module I will have:

```
void functionB() {
    printf("My Value: %s\n",luabind::object_cast<const char*>(value));
    printf("My Original value type: %d\n",luabind::type(value));
    value.push(L);
    luabind::object a1(luabind::from_stack(L,-1));
    printf("My Copy value type: %d\n",luabind::type(a1));
}
```

When I make functionA and functionB available from lua and call them in succession, the output will be:

```
My Value: yo
My Original value type: 4
My Copy value type: 0
```

As you can see, the object still references something that luabind can print. But when I try to push it on the stack and create a new object from the stack object, it will result in a nil value.

This only happens in this specific case. When I put everything into one function, it works fine. When I put the code into functions of the same module, it'll work fine. I haven't made a standalone test project yet, but I can't think of anything in my code interferring, the functions are called in direct succession from lua.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug? And if it's a bug, how come I've never heard of something like this?

Comment: I'd be curious if you could simplify the test case even further by removing Luabind and just using the Lua C API (obviously you can--by copy/pasting--but the question is whether the interesting "bug" is in Lua or Luabind).

Comment: @John Zwinck: Likely not, seeing as using a class wrapped by luabind is a prerequisite to trigger the bug. I don't even know if I want to try comprehending how putting a function in a class wrapped by luabind(the function itself doesn't need to be wrapped) could cause a change in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my test case was incomplete. functionB also needs to be in a class wrapped by luabind. I could "resolve" the issue by making the function in the class a proxy function, and calling a global function containing my code from there.

Comment: Then that sounds like a bug. I'm not sure why you hadn't heard of it - perhaps that particular scenario hasn't been done very often.  If you can get this as a small test program like this: https://github.com/rpavlik/luabind/blob/master/test/test_object_identity.cpp  I can add it to the test suite on my branch. You might try asking the luabind mailing list, especially if you have an automated test - someone there might know.